# HTML - Javascript - Change color of icon after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, favicon

On this jsfiddle, I want to change the color of the icon to red once its been liked(on 'unlike') and set color to black if its on 'like':

HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm liketoggle" name="like"><span>Like</span> <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
```

JS:

```
 $(".liketoggle").click(function() {
   $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fas far");
   $(this).find("span").text(function(i, v) {
     return v === 'Like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'
   })
 });
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding: 5em;
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/apbknwgf/12

Answer (score 0):

I've added the color to the `.far` class

```
.open .far {
  color: red;
}
```

JS

```
 $(".liketoggle").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("open");
   $(this).find("span").text(function(i, v) {
     return v === 'Like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'
   })
 });
```

You can play with css rules on `.far` or `.fas` class to get the desired output.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqkj2gtw/)

**EDIT**

If you have two buttons, you can add an other class to the second button and play with CSS selectors like this, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/198uo753/1/)

Comment: This works but what if I need to keep the same icon 'far fa-heart' and change its color to red. (forgot to mention this in the question)

Comment: This is right in some cases. What if the button in on 'Unlike' by default. see the following jsfiddle, whats the solution in this case? https://jsfiddle.net/u5v7ezbr/
The 'Like' by default needs to be black, and the 'Unlike' by default is red. In your jsfiddle, both are black as default.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a CSS rule:

```
.liketoggle i.fas {
  color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2qa04og

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by simply adding two classes 'like' and 'unlike', adding the colors you want to it and toggling them on click.

CSS:

```
.like .fa-heart{
  color: red;
}
.unlike .fa-heart{
  color: black;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(".liketoggle").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("like unlike");
   $(this).find("span").text(function(i, v) {
     return v === 'Like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'
   })
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fv9ds8a3/

Comment: This is right in some cases. What if the button in on 'Unlike' by default. see the following jsfiddle, whats the solution in this case? http://jsfiddle.net/zrndyc6L/

Comment: The 'Like' by default needs to be black, and the 'Unlike' is red. In your jsfiddle, both are red as default

Comment: You just have to switch the css colors as you like. You can add the class and text to the HTML to start with a specific color.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is switch the icons on click.  See the earlier posts at:
[Toggle icon on button via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193845/toggle-icon-on-button-via-javascript)

Hope this helps